# Improve reflection between extended implementors

Tags: reflection, interface, go

I have a `Result` interface which represents the minimum state of a result. Now there are different structs which implement the `Result` interface but also add own methods. One of them is `SpecialResult` which implemented the basic `Value()` method but also a special `Special()` method.

You can see this in the following snippet:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Result interface {
    Value() string
}

type SpecialResult struct {
    value string
}

func (r *SpecialResult) Value() string {
    return r.value
}

func (r *SpecialResult) Special() string {
    return "look I am special!!"
}

func main() {
    sr := &SpecialResult{
        value: "1234",
    }

    doSomething(sr)
}

func doSomething(r Result) {
    switch reflect.TypeOf(r).String() {
    case "*main.SpecialResult":
        fmt.Printf("%s, %s\n", r.Value(), r.(*SpecialResult).Special())
        break
    default:
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", r.Value())
    }
}
```

1. [Playground](https://gist.github.com/bodokaiser/6e0e424e66ce13364cde)
2. [Source](https://gist.github.com/bodokaiser/6e0e424e66ce13364cde)

When you read the last lines of code you might feel the same as I do: This looks very weird.

**Is there a better way to achieve the shown setup?**

Bodo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Type Assertions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Result interface {
    Value() string
}

type SpecialResult struct {
    value string
}

func (r *SpecialResult) Value() string {
    return r.value
}

func (r *SpecialResult) Special() string {
    return "look I am special!!"
}

func main() {
    sr := &SpecialResult{
        value: "1234",
    }

    doSomething(sr)
}

func doSomething(r Result) {
    if special, ok := r.(*SpecialResult); ok {
        fmt.Printf("%s, %s\n", special.Value(), special.Special())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", r.Value())
    }
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/dJi5kz3mq0)

Comment: is this also possible with a switch statement?